# Show the next data while looping over an array in typescript react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

So, I am trying to add some data to two different array in react typescript

```
const [deviceNames, setDeviceNames] = useState<Array<string>>([])
  const [serialNumbers, setSerialNumbers] = useState<Array<string>>([])
```

I am now looping over both the array here and displaying the content

```
{deviceNames.length > 0 &&
      serialNumbers.length > 0 &&
      deviceNames.map(deviceName => {
        return serialNumbers.map(serialNumber => {
          return (
            <CardDevice
              deviceName={deviceName}
              serialNumber={serialNumber}
            />
          )
        })
      })}
```

I am adding data to these array by clicking on a button and then showing modal and then like this

```
 onSubmit = (values: any) => {
    clearError()
    setAddDevice(false)
    setDeviceNames(deviceName => [...deviceName, values.deviceName])
    setSerialNumbers(serialNumber => [...serialNumber, values.serialNumber])
  }
```

I am using react hook form.
So what i want is whenever i loop over both the arrays, each time it should display the content which was just added in the array the new one not the last one again which was already added and displayed. I hope i am able to make some point here. It does the job but whenever user enters new device after adding one, it add the old one again and then the new one and then again and then again same thing.
i just want to display just one new item which was just last added to an array by the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically i answered my own question:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [addCardData, setAddCardData] = useState("");
  const [addCards, setAddCards] = useState<Array<string>>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setAddCardData(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setAddCards(prevState => [...prevState, addCardData]);
  };
  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{ textAlign: "center", margin: "0 auto", marginTop: "10em" }}
    >
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Add any text" />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      {addCards.map(addCard => (
        <h3>{addCard}</h3>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some more Dynamic Approach:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TextInput } from "./components/TextInput";

interface Device {
  deviceName: string;
  serialNumber: string | number;
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [deviceName, setDeviceName] = useState("");
  const [serialNumber, setSerialNumber] = useState("");
  const [deviceInfos, setDeviceInfos] = useState<Device[]>([]);

  const handleDeviceChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setDeviceName(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleSerialChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSerialNumber(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void => {
    event.preventDefault();
    addDevice();
    setDeviceName("");
    setSerialNumber("");
  };

  const addDevice = () => {
    const newDevice: Device[] = [
      ...deviceInfos,
      { deviceName: deviceName, serialNumber: serialNumber }
    ];
    setDeviceInfos(newDevice);
  };
  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{ textAlign: "center", margin: "0 auto", marginTop: "10em" }}
    >
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextInput
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add Device Name"
          handleChange={handleDeviceChange}
          value={deviceName}
        />
        <TextInput
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add fuck"
          handleChange={handleSerialChange}
          value={serialNumber}
        />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
      {deviceInfos.map((device, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <h3>{device.deviceName}</h3>
          <h3>{device.serialNumber}</h3>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Much Better Approach i used in the production**

```
  const ProfileDevices: React.FC<Props> = ({ onSubmit }) => {
      const [addDevice, setAddDevice] = useState(false)
      const [deviceInfos, setDeviceInfos] = useState<Device[]>([])

      const { register, handleSubmit, errors, clearError } = useForm({
        mode: 'onSubmit',
      })
      const addDevices: any = () => {
        setAddDevice(true)
      }

      onSubmit = (values: any) => {
        clearError()
        setAddDevice(false)
        const newDevice: Device[] = [
          ...deviceInfos,
          { deviceName: values.deviceName, serialNumber: values.serialNumber },
        ]
        setDeviceInfos(newDevice)
      }

      return (
        <ProfileContentContainer>
          <ProfileHeader>
            <ProfileTitle>Devices</ProfileTitle>

            <ProfileActions>
              <Button
                type="button"
                bgType="fill"
                size="default"
                label="Add Device"
                onClick={addDevices}
              />
            </ProfileActions>
          </ProfileHeader>
          {console.log(deviceInfos)}
          <DeviceList>
            <CardDevice deviceName="Device Name" serialNumber="QR10001123456788" />
            <CardDevice deviceName="Device Name" serialNumber="QR10001123456789" />
            {deviceInfos.map((device, i) => (
              <CardDevice
                key={i}
                deviceName={device.deviceName}
                serialNumber={device.serialNumber}
              />
            ))}
          </DeviceList>
          <Modal isActive={addDevice} toggleModal={() => setAddDevice(false)}>
            <ModalContent>
              <ModalHeader title="Add Device" />
              <AuthForm
                onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                className="modalAddDeviceForm"
              >
                <InputText
                  placeholder="DeviceName"
                  name="deviceName"
                  type="text"
                  register={register({ required: true, maxLength: 10 })}
                  hasError={errors.deviceName}
                  errorMessage={
                    errors.serialNumber ? errors.serialNumber.message : undefined
                  }
                />
                <InputText
                  placeholder="Serial Number"
                  name="serialNumber"
                  type="text"
                  register={register({ required: true, maxLength: 10 })}
                  hasError={errors.serialNumber}
                  errorMessage={
                    errors.serialNumber ? errors.serialNumber.message : undefined
                  }
                />
                <Button type="submit" bgType="fill" size="default" label="Add" />
              </AuthForm>
              <ModalActions></ModalActions>
            </ModalContent>
          </Modal>
        </ProfileContentContainer>
      )
    }

    export default ProfileDevices
```